# Internet Explorer 9 sometimes scrolls jerkily using arrow keys

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard, internet-explorer-9, scrolling

I have one user who finds that scrolling up and down using arrow keys in Internet Explorer, for some sites, some of the time (but often for the sites it happens with), is jerky and definitely slow.

It did not happen for my login on the same machine, until I tested it again just as I wrote up this question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, given this is an intermittent problem, there's a more specific issue that web sites might be able to help to avoid, but [this workaround](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_vista/why-is-scrolling-in-ie9-so-slow-and-jerky/b9d64bc9-db55-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=0c02a6a8-28d7-4a3f-8e3b-2c4b09792ecb) does solve the issue as far as I can see:

> Turn off Smooth Scrolling.

That's Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Browsing > Uncheck "Use smooth scrolling" and OK.

It fixes the problem immediately.